# Stata: Identifying unique observations that differ on all variables, by group

Tags: stata

My Stata dataset contains observations on constituent components of products created by different players in a simulation.
I would like to retain only the products (created by each player) that consist of distinct and unique components, i.e. 
identify the observations (by player_id) which differ on ALL variables.

The data are:

> > > ```
> > >  +---------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+
> > > | Product | Player id | Component1 | Component2 | Component3 |
> > > +---------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+
> > > |       1 |         1 |          1 |          2 |          3 |
> > > |       2 |         1 |          1 |          5 |          9 |
> > > |       3 |         1 |          7 |          8 |          9 |
> > > |       4 |         2 |          4 |          5 |          6 |
> > > |       5 |         2 |          4 |          5 |          9 |
> > > |       6 |         2 |          7 |          8 |          9 |
> > > +---------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+
> > > ```

The desirable outcome should allow me to have the following outcome:

> > > > ```
> > > >  +---------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+
> > > > | Product | Player id | Component1 | Component2 | Component3 |
> > > > +---------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+
> > > > |       1 |         1 |          1 |          2 |          3 |
> > > > |       3 |         1 |          7 |          8 |          9 |
> > > > |       4 |         2 |          4 |          5 |          6 |
> > > > |       6 |         2 |          7 |          8 |          9 |
> > > > +---------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+
> > > > ```

As one can see, Product 2 should be removed because it has common component 1 with product 1 and common component 3 with product 3; similarly product 5 should be removed because it shares components 1 and 2 with product 4, and component 3 with product 6.

The remaining products (by player) should be kept because they draw on distinct non-overlapping components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each combination of components to be totally new for each distinct Player, it is necessary and sufficient that all components occur for the first time for that Player. Therefore we keep track of first occurrences of each component and drop any observations with later occurrences of that component.

The same toy data (but with some shorter variable names):

```
input Product Player_id C1 C2 C3 
   1          1           1           2           3 
   2          1           1           5           9 
   3          1           7           8           9 
   4          2           4           5           6 
   5          2           4           5           9 
   6          2           7           8           9 
end
```

It is not clear whether `Product` plays the same role as observation number: regardless of that we can create a variable holding observation numbers.

```
gen long obs = _n
```

Now we are going to loop over components, 9 of them in this example.

```
qui forval i = 1/9 {
```

For each component: it's found if it's any of the three components. That is an indicator variable, 1 if true and 0 if false:

```
    gen found = C1 == `i' | C2 == `i' | C3 == `i'
```

There is a neat alternative:

```
    gen found = inlist(`i', C1, C2, C3)
```

We want to keep track of the first occurrence, which is the minimum observation number if `found` is true, and we do that separately by `Player_id`. The division here by the indicator variable produces `obs` if `found` is 1 and missing otherwise. The missings are just ignored by `egen` unless all values are returned as missing.

```
    egen first = min(obs / found), by(Player_id)
```

Now what we do is `drop` occurrences if they are not the first, and `drop` our accounting variables, so they can be re-created next time round the loop:

```
    drop if obs > first & found
    drop first found 
}
```

Here's the result:

```
      +-----------------------------------------+
      | Product   Player~d   C1   C2   C3   obs |
      |-----------------------------------------|
   1. |       1          1    1    2    3     1 |
   2. |       3          1    7    8    9     3 |
   3. |       4          2    4    5    6     4 |
   4. |       6          2    7    8    9     6 |
      +-----------------------------------------+
```

Note that this algorithm is sensitive to the order of the observations. If you start with `1 5 9` then neither `1 2 3` or `7 8 9` are acceptable in addition. Similarly with `4 5 9`; `4 5 6` and `7 8 9` don't make the cut.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your consideration, Nick. I have tested your solution but it appears that the order in which observations are eliminated matters for this problem.  I have tried to develop an alternative solution and to sequentially eliminate products based on pairwise value comparisons within a group: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393424/stata-sequential-elimination-of-observations-based-on-pairwise-comparisons-with